# JavaScript For loop vs for in does not work

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I wrote two functions named some and every to expect to get results shown as below:

```
console.log(every([NaN, NaN, NaN], isNaN));
// → true

console.log(every([NaN, NaN, 4], isNaN));
// → false

console.log(some([NaN, 3, 4], isNaN));
// → true

console.log(some([2, 3, 4], isNaN));
// → false
```

My functions are:

```
function every(array,predicate){
  for (var element in array){
    if (!predicate(element))
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function some(array, predicate){
  for (var element in array){
    if (predicate(element))
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

But the results are all `false`

Once I change the `for...in` to `for` loop, the answers are correct.

```
function every(array, predicate) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (!predicate(array[i]))
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function some(array, predicate) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (predicate(array[i]))
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Why `for..in` can not result in the correct answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loop through array in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use a traditional `for` loop, consider using a `for…of` loop, which iterates through the elements in an array. `for…in` iterates through the keys.

```
function every (array, predicate) {
    for (var element of array) {
        if (!predicate(element)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

[docs for `for…of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Note: per the documentation, this requires an implementation that runs the ES6 Harmony proposal.

Answer (score 3):

`for..in` iterates through the *property names* of the object you are iterating over.

In this case, those would be `0`, `1`, `2`, so your attempt is calling the predicate on those and not the actual array elements.

[Don't use `for..in` with arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea). The order of iteration is not guaranteed and it can wind up iterating over non-index properties.